# My httpd server is often down for no reason

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, httpd

This is report from chkservd

```
Server: host.superhostsite.com
Primary IP: 76.73.1.154
Service:    httpd
Notification Type:  failed  

Notification:   httpd failed @ Wed Jul 24 19:44:06 2013. A restart was attempted automagically.
Service Check Method:   [socket connect] 
Reason: Unable to connect to port 80 on 127.0.0.1: Connection refused: Died at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/TailWatch/ChkServd.pm line 782.
Number of Restart Attempts: 1
Memory Information: •   Used: 422MB 
•   Available: 15186MB 
•   Installed: 15607MB 
Load Information:   0.00 0.02 0.00
Uptime: 0 days, 0 hours, 10 seconds
IOStat Information: avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.13    0.00    0.11    0.03    0.00   99.74
Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sdb              12.59       142.49        75.85      92100      49024
sda               5.78       154.19        47.24      99660      30536
sdc               0.71         5.70         0.01       3682          8
sdd              32.42       788.28        79.74     509510      51541
ChkServd Version:   15.2
```

top is low. CPU has 32 cores and 64 GB memory. All drives are SSDs

Top shows low cpu usage.

I think I got to check some log. Basically chkservd found that server CPU usage is low

Comment: Check `dmesg`, the debug log, and any application logs for the httpd service.

Comment: (16GB ram looks like)   But it appears your machine may have gone to sleep and been rebooted, uptime is 10 seconds as of that report.